# Cómo puedo convertir un proyecto completo en Libreria DLL

Tags: c++, qt

Cómo puedo convertir un proyecto completo en C++ en **DLL**, para usar en mis otros proyectos?

He buscado por internet sobre cómo convertirlo, pero nunca lo intentando en todo, en **`C#`** usando la clase e importándola a mi programa principal.

En conclusión, como puedo convertir un completo proyecto en DLL, y como sería en este caso la llamada a sus métodos.

Como Ide estoy usando **`Qt`** por lo que es aún más difícil encontrar información al respecto.

Alguna sugerencia para empezar emigrar mi proyecto hecho en QT, convertir en una **Librería DLL** y poder incluir características del mismo a mis otros proyectos.

Comment: Los dlls son archivos que apuntan a librerías, Qt es una herramienta poderosa que te ayuda a generar dlls, mira este link: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sharedlibrary.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la documentación de **Qt** muestra cómo crear **librerías dinámicas**:

- [Creating Shared Libraries](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sharedlibrary.html) **Creando bibliotecas compartidas**